# Kendo UI panelbar

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-panelbar

I'm new with Kendo UI PanelBar.  I would like to expand the panelbar using javacript when the user click on a button.  Thanks for your help.

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
            .Name("TestBar")
            .Items(panelbar =>
            {
                panelbar.Add().Text("Additional Information")
                .Content(@<text>@Html.Partial("Req") </text>);
            })
        )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. Call below funciton in your button click event.

```
<script>
    function ExpandItemInPanelBar(){
        var panelBar = $("#TestBar").data("kendoPanelBar");
        // I have set 0 in 'eq(0)' so it will expand first item you can change it as per your code
        panelBar.select(panelBar.element.children("li").eq(0));

        var item = panelBar.select();
        panelBar.expand(item);
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Update 1:

```
//Check any item is expanded in panelbar
if(panelBar.element.children("li").hasClass("k-state-active") == true)
{
    alert('items(s) expanded');
}

//Check every item is expanded or not in panelbar
items =  panelBar.element.children("li");
for(var i = 0 ; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    if($(items[i].hasClass('k-state-active'))
    {
        alert('this item is expanded');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jayesh.  It worked.  Is there a way to disable the collapse/expand? I would like to make the panel expanded at all time.

Comment: Please add Select event in your PanelBar, then inside your select event write 'e.preventDefault();'. You can add select event by using below link. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/panelbar/events.html

Comment: Please try with above solution. Let me know if any concern, I will provide sample demo for same.

Comment: Thank you Jayess.  How do I check if the panel is expanded or not?

Comment: @Jayesh will `e.preventDefault()` prevent you from expanding it through the script in your answer? Or will it only prevent mouseclicks?

Comment: prevent you from expanding.

Comment: I was trying this just now and e.preventDefault() didn't work in a Select event handler.  However it did work for Expand and Collapse.